# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion

From the SE [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) currently linked at the top of meta:

> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger.
>   You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What
>   would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes
>   what your site is about. Every word counts!

Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:

- the tagline
- the motto
- the blurb under the logo
- a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
- [perhaps eventually](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/) the domain name in some form

For more detail see: *[Stack Exchange Naming for Dummies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/)*

Comment: *Did you know 97% of internets are being monitored right now? **THAT'S BULLSHIT! USE TOR!***

Comment: Here's something to consider.  I have over 10K over all the SE sites I participate in, and only today found this one because of a question I asked on Google.  I ended up joining and posting a question here just now.  So there was no elevator speech required in my case.  There are some great questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Tor.SE is the information sharing site about Tor - the network that enables information sharing, even when people try to prevent it.

Comment: Ok, I think it's slightly cheesy, but it'll do for a first attempt. I might be able to come up with something better later.